# Android studio AVD Manager emulator failed to download in windows 10 it happen so many time

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

I'm trying to install new AVD Manager using Android Studio's but it fails because of my internet problems and it re-starts downloading from the start.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i solve that problem ,
=> Select low AVD Manager with low API (B'cos i have only 4 GB Ram)
=> In Advance Setting increase your AVD Manager Ram 
it's work fine

Thank You...